# Similar functionality as in Dev HTTP Client using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, http-headers

Right now I am working with `AngularJS` on a web interface which should have similar behavior like [Dev HTTP Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dev-http-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm). I can't find a way how to add headers in the way like DHC does.

I'm trying to make it somehow like this, but it isn't working since array is initialized empty:

```
<div ng-repeat="header in headersCollection.headers">
    <input ng-model="header.name" type="text"/> : 
    <input ng-model="header.value" type="text"/>
</div>
<button type="button" ng-click="addNewHeader()">Add</button>
```

Headers should be stored inside this object and be available for creating, editing and removing through web interface. Just like in DHC.

```
$rootScope.headersCollection = {
            headers : []
}
```

Any idea / link / answer are highly appreciated and answered immidiately.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make an "empty" header object in the headers collection. See http://jsfiddle.net/e8MEx/
Of course you will want to throw in some validation to make sure they are values before adding another one and potentially add the ability to remove an item:

JavaScript:

```
var mod = angular.module("myApp", []);

mod.run(["$rootScope", function($rootScope) {
    //start the array with one empty value for header
    $rootScope.headersCollection = {
        headers : [{name: "", value: ""}]
    }
}]);

mod.controller("MainController", ["$scope", "$rootScope", function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.headersCollection = $rootScope.headersCollection
    $scope.addNewHeader = function () {
        //push a new empty value onto the array.
        $scope.headersCollection.headers.push({name: "", value: ""});
    }
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainController">
    <div ng-repeat="header in headersCollection.headers">
        <input ng-model="header.name" type="text"/> : 
        <input ng-model="header.value" type="text"/>
    </div>
    <button type="button" ng-click="addNewHeader()">Add</button>

    <p>{{headersCollection.headers}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I just came up with similar solution :) Thank you for your reply.